# Why page.goto always returns Timeout error?

Tags: timeout, puppeteer

## Steps to reproduce

- Puppeteer version: 2.1.1
- Platform / OS version: Windows
- URLs (if applicable): Any
- Node.js version: 12.6.0

I tried to use Puppeteer but every single page I use on page.goto gives me TimeoutError.

I'm currently using example code, and isn't working:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://news.ycombinator.com', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
  await page.pdf({path: 'hn.pdf', format: 'A4'});

  await browser.close();
})();
```

The results are always:

> TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded

Comment: have you tried setting headless to false and see whether the page loads?

Comment: Your code is working for me.

Comment: Yes, I set to headless and nothing's load.